# Cannot get balances in "tx-service"

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe

Upon typing "tx-service" and "balances", getting an error "Cannot get balances: b''"

Comment: Can you provide us what tool are you using? And on what platform?

Comment: @haxerl, it’s the latest Safe-CLI/Polygon on macOS